# Show math formula in emacs when coding

Tags: latex, display

Is it possible that emacs shows real formulas in the editor if they are written in Latex or similiar? I am asking because it would be much more readable if you are coding (in lets say python or C++) and the comments contain real formulas instead of something like this

```
// Calculate average for $\mu_1 = \frac{1}{n} ~ \sum_{1=i}^n ~ x_i$
```

Is there a plugin which compiles Latex code in a comment to a picture and display it in the editor?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. See `pretty-symbols` package. It can look like this, for example, when coding Python, or any other language:

[image]

Comment: Should I use `pretty-symbols` or `latex-pretty-symbols`?

Answer (score 3):

<s>[TeXfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/TeXfrag/blob/master/TeXfrag.el)</s> [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/TeXfrag/blob/master/texfrag.el) shows doxygen-formulas embraced by `\f[display formula\f]` or `\f$embedded formula\f$` as images.

The regular expressions and also the functions for parsing the formulas can be customized.

TeXfrag works by:

1. copying the formulas from the source code buffer to a (hidden) LaTeX buffer
2. running [preview-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html) there and
3. moving the overlays back to the source code buffer.

The context menus of `preview` work for the images in the source code buffer.
There is also a minor-mode menu which allows you to generate the images for the full buffer or just the images around point.

Example:
The upper buffer shows a section of a doxygen-comment in a c-file with overlaid images for the equation fragments the lower buffer shows the same section with the overlays removed.

[image: emacs screenshot with rendered formulas in doxygen comments]

EDIT: Note that `TeXfrag` has been renamed to `texfrag` to fulfill the requirements of `melpa`. `texfrag` has been reviewed and accepted by `melpa`. If you have `melpa` in `package-archives` you can install `texfrag` via `package-install`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that an actual image would be more trouble than it's worth in `c++-mode` or `python-mode`.  It could work in `org-mode` though, which has a mechanism for storing the images and refreshing them.  Even then, it's awkward for scrolling if the image has a large height.

But you can still fontify bits if you want. For instance, here's my setup for font-locking doxygen tags in C++:

```cl
(defface font-lock-doxygen-face
    '((nil (:foreground "SaddleBrown" :background "#f7f7f7")))
  "Special face to highlight doxygen tags such as <tt>...</tt>
and <code>...</code>."
  :group 'font-lock-highlighting-faces)

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'c++-mode
 '(("\\(<\\(?:code\\|tt\\)>\"?\\)\\([^<]*?\\)\\(\"?</\\(?:code\\|tt\\)>\\)"
    (0 (prog1 ()
         (let* ((expr (match-string-no-properties 2))
                (expr-len (length expr)))
           (if (eq 1 expr-len)
               (compose-region (match-beginning 0)
                               (match-end 0)
                               (aref expr 0))
             (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                             (1+ (match-end 1))
                             (aref expr 0))
             (compose-region (1- (match-beginning 3))
                             (match-end 3)
                             (aref expr (1- expr-len)))))))
    (0 'font-lock-doxygen-face t))))
```

It will replace `<tt>foo</tt>` and `<code>bar</code>` with colored symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is the `latex-math-preview` package. It allows one to view "real formulas in the editor" in a separate buffer (or to save the formula image to a file). Simply invoke `latex-math-preview-expression` while the point is on an expression.